# iframe extends beyond element

Tags: html, css, iframe

I added an iframe to a zone/page section in sharepoint.
The problem I am having is when the window is sized smaller or viewed on mobile, the iframe extends beyond the element is was put in.

I have tried using display: block in the div I put the iframe in, overflow: hidden, and so far no luck.

Any suggestions?

```
<div>
<p align="center"> 
<iframe src="https://wheeldecide.com/e.php?c1=Stand+Up+and+Stretch&amp;c2=Drink+Some+Water&amp;    c3=Call+a+Colleague&amp;c4=Straighten+Up+Your+Workspace&amp;c5=Spend+5+Min+With+Your+Pet&amp;c6=Eat+a+Healthy+Snack&amp;c7=Step+Outside+for+5+Min&amp;c8=Take+a+Quick+Walk&amp;cols=ab2328,53565a,7a99ac,71cc98,da291c&amp;t=Wellness+Activity+Selector&amp;time=5&amp;tcol=000000,ffffff&amp; scrolling="no" width="600" height="500" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: add style="max-width:100%" to the iframe tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set a max-width/height in percentage, so just add the style max-width:100% and max-height:100%!